# App to hide windows while sharing the screen

Tags: macos, mac, screen-sharing

Do you know of a way or app to selectively hide windows during screen sharing?

My goal: I use Microsoft Teams, share the entire screen, but want to make sure that e.g. the Spark app (email client) is never transferred.

Comment: Move them to another space.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can exclude individual windows from the app. If I remember correctly, MS Teams offers the ability to share your window/application or your entire desktop. You could:

- switch to just the individual app you want to share, or
- minimize the app you don't want to share when sharing your screen